# How do I trigger a local notifications at future time and then every min after that time until stopped

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

### Aim

I'm looking to establish if it's still posible to trigger an Swift local notifications at a destingated time (say every day at 15:00) and then every min after that time until it's stopped.

### Why I think it could be done

I know this could be done in the past as I have an reminder app I use daily "Alarmed" that does exactly this! It allows you to set up to 64 alarms (the current limit for scheduled local notifications) all to go off at once. Then if you force kill the app and wait all 64 notifications go off. If you then ignore them they keep going off every min forever (or for longer than 2 hours)! Exactly what I want for my own app...

I've also tested that app (Alarmed) with no access to location tracking and as I said fully force closed so it's not using any re-scheduling tricks...

### Issue

I can not find a way to do it with the UNMutableNotificationContent API. Setting the trigger type to "UNCalendarNotificationTrigger". e.g.: `let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: DateComponents(year: 2022, month: 1, hour: 10, minute: 25), repeats: true)` does trigger at the specified day/time but doesn't repeate every minuite after that time if ignored/missed and `let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats: true)` does repeate every min until stopped but starts repeating straight away (which seems like a pointless feature to me)!

I guess what I'm trying to do is combine the two!
Having the Calendar one to set the initial time the first notification goes off and then the Time Interval one continues the notifications from then on every min... but that seems to not be not posible.

### Question

Does anyone have any ideas what API's (ether current or say 7 years old when the app was last updated) that allows this? Even if it's not posible with the current API it's more a curiosity thing now as I've spend days trying to work out how to do it!

Comment: You cannot do it with UNNotificationCenter. You would have to use th deprecated [`UILocalnotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification) api

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Paulw11 that's exactly what I wanted to KNOW, that the option did exist and is no longer avalible in the current APIs.

Comment: @Paulw11 do you want to flesh that out into an answer I can mark as answered and close this off for future visitors?